# VBA Excel Error Run-Time error 53-file not found

Tags: excel, vba

this code used to run perfectly now is having time error 53, file not found. Not sure what is wrong

```
 Sub printxxx()
' Print_quote XXX Macro

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
Worksheets("Quote").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$H$6:$Z$133"
 strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile                           
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName).ParentFolder.Name & " XXXQuote ", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True                      
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait                                                     
End Sub
```

Comment: Set the filename to an actual variable that you can check first before trying to use it so you can make sure it's getting set to what you expect. Use `MsgBox` or `Debug.Print` to check it first.

Comment: what line is thowing the error? where is `strFile` defined and set?

Comment: i've used MsBox and it shows https://applesgreengroupau-my.sharepoint.com/personal/juanito_carbonblue_com_au/Documents/Lighting/Projects/Littil/CobramHospital/RESA1 rev6.50 Cobram Hospital.xlsm